# Get last modified data older than 30 days from now in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

I wrote the code for the condition: delete data where LastModifiedDate is older than 30days from today.

Code:

```
data= [SELECT Id, Name, Type, Status, LastModifiedDate FROM Account ];

            for(Account account : data)
                {
                    Integer daysCount = (system.today()).daysBetween(Date.valueOf(account.LastModifiedDate));
                    if(daysCount>30){
                        //Purge data
                        delete account ;
                    }
                }
```

But should write above logic in the SOQL query itself to get data which is older than 30days from now to delete. I tried with the below SOQL but it gives all records even latest records too.

```
  data = [SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate FROM Accont where  LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS: 30];
```

Comment: If you want data last modified more than 30 days ago, you need `WHERE LastModifiedDate > LAST_N_DAYS:30`. What you have there, `WHERE LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:30` shouldn't get all records, but only those modified within the last 30 days.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor Your `>` should be `<`, by the way.

Comment: when I gave "LastModifiedDate > LAST_N_DAYS:30" or "LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:30", it returns empty records even I have data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a filter without needing a variable, via LAST_N_DAYS:

```
data = [SELECT LastModifiedDate 
        FROM Account 
        WHERE LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:30];
```

This returns records that haven't been modified in 30 days.

Also see [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) for other alternatives.

Comment: The above query giving empty records.

Comment: @RKCY If so, then there aren't any such records.

Comment: @sfdcfox-  Yes, I had verified in another account..This above query works great. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this on SOQL and it will work:

SELECT name, Format(LastModifiedDate)
FROM Account
WHERE LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:01

Comment: How does this help them get records older than 30 days as the question asked when you're filter specifies one day?